# How to parse URLs queried from model?

Tags: django

I want to retrieve the url from FeedSource class model to save the feed in my site

In **models.py**

```
 class FeedSource(models.Model):
      url = models.URLField(max_length=400, blank=True)
      is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Feed(models.Model):
    feedsource = models.ForeignKey(FeedSource, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

In **apps.py**

```
from feed.models import Feed, FeedSource
import feedparser
d = feedparser.parse('http://feeds.feedburner.com/abc/')
```

I expect the output to retrieve the url from the FeedSource model and save the feed in my site. But I have done it with manual url that is:

```
d = feedparser.parse('http://feeds.feedburner.com/abc/')
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects

Comment: Your question is not clear. Where are you having difficulties?

Comment: With 'd = feedparser.parse('http://feeds.feedburner.com/ycombinator/')'  the feed of the site called ycombinator is displayed. i do not want to chnage the feedparser.parse(/.../) every time. So the url should automatically  retrieve the feed from the entered url in FeedSource and display in my site admin

Comment: Yes but you have still not said what you're finding difficult, nor what you tried or where it went wrong.

Comment: I want to know what changes should be done in the d = feedparser.parse(??) to retrieve the url from the model class or any code that needs to be added in the above code.

Comment: Rather than putting the RSS feed one at a time, I want feedparser.parse to retrieve the url automatically from model.

Comment: It's like how to pass the values of feedsource url in feedparser.parse().